# What generates the value of an int primary key for users with ASP.NET Identity 2?

Tags: asp.net-identity

It's my understanding with ASP.NET Identity 2 you will be able to have a PK of int for Users and Roles.  I like the idea of this very much.

But currently ASP.NET Identity 1.0 seems to generate a GUID which is converted to a string. I understand how to change to the PK being an int but what else is needed. If my PK's are integers then will it create an integer ID for me automatically when I create a new user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF by default knows how to generate int identities unlike Guids, so you shouldn't have to do anything regarding key generation once you switch the primary key type to integer.

Comment: I had a situation where EF was attempting to insert a user with an explicit ID of 0 ("Cannot Insert Explicit Value For Identity Column..."),
I had to add "modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(databaseGeneratedOption: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); to my OnModelCreating method