# How to generate my own primary key for ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, primary-key

I have already updated my ASP.NET Identity code to use a long (bigint in SQL) instead of a GUID/string for the user primary key. Now I would like to use a key generator to create my own primary keys rather than have the Entity Framework generate sequential keys. I'm not sure what class(es) or method(s) to edit or override to accomplish this.

Google keeps pointing me to how to change the PK type which I've already figured out. A [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861461/what-generates-the-value-of-an-int-primary-key-for-users-with-asp-net-identity-2) wants to know how the key gets generated (answer: by EF), but doesn't ask how to do it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find all clases you have to "implement" (at least inherit from). And some small needed changes.
[ASP.NET Identity 2 Change Primary Key Type to Integer on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777733/ASP-NET-Identity-Change-Primary-Key)

If you also want to generate your own Id's (don't let SQL Server let generate them), may you have to adjust the PK like in your linked post.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I mentioned twice in my post that I've already changed the type. I'm looking for how to generate my own keys.

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<*entityname*>().Property(m => m.*fieldname*)
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None); don't work?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting a SQL database you can use sequence. This will allow you to create a base PK and set increments for the next PK.

Comment: I want to programmatically assign my keys in code (C#).